# How to perform driver.findElement() by passing String to the method

Tags: java, selenium

I Have a method that automatically returns String that can be passed to FindElement() method.
for eg:I have a method that returns String By.cssSelector(input[id='a']).I am storing it in to a variable x.

but if i try to pass this as driver.findElement(x),I am getting an error.

> May i know how to type cast String in to Webelement

Comment: It just doesn't sound quite right. Could you elaborate more on why is it coming as a string and can you trust the source?

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` would then be a String, and `findElement(By)` only accepts a By.

> May i know how to type cast String into a WebElement

This cannot be done.  What CAN be done, is have a default to CSS (or any other selector), for example, (a modified excerpt from the [getting-started-with-selenium](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework):

```
/**
 * Click an element.
 * @param css The css element to click.
 * @return
 */
public void click(String css) {
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(css)).click();
}
```

That way you can do:

```
click("input#a");
click("button#login");
```

Comment: I guess `Click` does not return anything!!!. It could be WebElement, if we don't perform any operation.

Comment: This was a "modified excerpt" `:)` it was taken from [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java#L191) and would return itself for a fluent-interface.